# how do I convert kinect trajectory matrix to 4x4 homogeneus matrix (example)

Tags: c++, matrix, kinect, point-cloud-library, slam-algorithm

Recently I used RGBD-Slam to obtain kinect camera trajectory. Each frame will have this:

> **timestamp tx ty tz qx qy qz qw**

**tx ty tz** give the position of the optical center of the color camera with respect to the world origin as defined by the motion capture system.

**qx qy qz qw** give the orientation of the optical center of the color camera in form of a unit quaternion with respect to the world origin as defined by the motion capture system.

I need to convert it to 4x4 homogeneous transformation matrix. Any hints to solve this?. Let's say the example as follows:

> **1421307756.191874 0.004530 0.050319 0.003332 0.003734 0.023578 -0.054199 0.998245**

so,

**timestamp**: 1421307756.191874 ; **tx**: 0.004530

**ty**: 0.050319 ; **tz**: 0.003332

**qx**: 0.003734 ; **qy**: 0.023578

**qz**: -0.054199 ; **qw**: 0.998245

and,
**fx** = 525.0; **fy** = 525.0; // default focal length

**cx** = 319.5; **cy** = 239.5; // default optical center

Kind assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: have you sloved the problem?? I don't understand either

Answer (score -1, accepted):

extracting angle and axis of the quaternion shouldn't be hard right ?
then you, can find the general expression of a rotation matrix with a given axis

then just combining the obtained matrix with the translation matrix in the right order should do the trick

it's my first post plz be indulgent if I'm saying shit :-P